# Loadable object for Sub::Name

Tags: linux, perl

I am trying to use wkhtmltopdf to generate pdfs. I've got a perl script that does the job in Windows. I'm now trying to move it to my production linux box (shared hosting). I can create a pdf on the linux box with wkhtmlpdf but am having issues with the perl script. I'm now getting an error "Can't locate loadable object for module Sub::Name in @INC..."

Through my searches I've found that this could be due to a dependence on auto::Sub::Name::Name.dll. I've uploaded this to my linux server (even though its a windows-specific file) but still getting the same error message "Can't locate loadable object for module Sub::Name in @INC...".

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're missing is a version of Sub::Name that works on linux. You can't just copy XS modules from one system to another and have them work. Install Sub::Name from CPAN or through your distribution's packaging system.

Comment: Just copy the module file (.pm) in the proper directory (one from @INC) and you should be fine.

Comment: @fengshaun no, that's what user374436 already did. It doesn't work with a module that uses XS.